# How to find radix?

Tags: number-systems

$\sqrt{(144)_r} =(12)_r$

I have tried $\sqrt{r^2+4r+4} =r+2$

From this, I am unable to find the value of $r$. Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: It holds identically for any radix $r > 4$. You need $r > 4$ else $4$ is not a legal digit, base $r$.

Comment: @quasi - No, it holds for all $r \ge -2$

Comment: @steven gregory: In this context, the subscript $r$ is intended as denoting the base.  A base can't be negative, and must be greater than the largest digit.

Comment: Why can't a base be negative? It would be wierd that $(12)_r = 0_r$ but would it lead to any contradictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, proceed as follows
$$\begin{align*} \sqrt{(144)_r}&=\sqrt{r^2+4r+4}
\\ &= \sqrt{(r+2)^2}
\\&=  (r+2)
\\&=(12)_r
\end{align*}$$
$LHS=RHS$

The equation is true for any $r,$ but base $r$ in $(144)_r$ with a digit of $4$, so $r>4$

Comment: digits contain in the number must be less than base i got it